# Scalaz 7 - why using type alias results in ambigous typeclass resolution for Reader

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

Code to test with:

```
import scalaz.{Reader, Applicative}

class ReaderInstanceTest {

  type IntReader[A] = Reader[Int, A]
  val a = Applicative[({type l[A] = Reader[Int, A]})#l] // fine

  val b = Applicative[IntReader]
  //                 ^ ambigous implicit values
  //                   both method kleisliMonadReader ..
  //                   and method kleisliIdMonadReader ..
}
```

Is this related to Scala's [higher-order unification for type constructor inference](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2712) ticket? If so (and even if not), could you describe what happens here in the a and b cases?

Do you have guidelines about when to use type lambda and when to use a type alias so that everything works out on the long run without unexpected errors?

Comment: Thanks for reporting, I need to rearrange the implicits in `KleisliInstances` to get scalac to pick one, rather than report the ambiguity error. (I had thought that all the bases were covered by this test: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/tests/src/test/scala/scalaz/KleisliTest.scala#L38)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is related to SI-2712.

`kleisliIdMonadReader` exists solely to guide type inference; it just forwards to `kleisliMonadReader`. By providing the type alias `IntReader`, scalac doesn't need this assistance, and can infer the type arguments for `kleisliMonadReader` directly. This leads to the ambiguity.

I've just committed a remedy: we can prioritize these implicits relative to each other, by defining one in a subclass.

https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/commit/6f9ae5f